# PDO ignoring PDO::CASE_NATURAL on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, case-sensitive

On my local dev machine (MAMP) my MySQL queries return with their correct case. However on my shared hosting server my results are lowercase when using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

I've tried the following:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL);
```

But it seems to have no effect, what am I missing?

Example:

```
$findUpload = $db->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM
        uploads
    WHERE 
        slug = :slug
    LIMIT 1
');
$findUpload->execute(array(
    ':slug' => $_GET['entry']
));
```

`$_GET['entry']` is `Zcbc`

When I do

```
$getUpload = $findUpload->fetchAll(); // switched to fetchAll temporarily 
$singleUpload = $getUpload[0];
```

echo $singleUpload['slug'] // ouputs `zcbc`

Somewhere converting my previously mixed case string into all lowercase. Both the $_GET variable and the MySQL entry are mixed cased strings.

Comment: No error, it just still returns the value as lowercase on the remote server only

Comment: you want them to be upper case?

Comment: if yes try this one PDO::CASE_UPPER: Force column names to upper case.

Comment: No I want them to be the case they are in the database. So if a value is "pDc" I want it to be returned to PHP as "pDc", currently it's returning "pdc" (all lowercase)

Comment: it sounds weird because it should be correct clear your cache Hope someone helps you.

Comment: Does this phenomenon occur when you connect through terminal?

Comment: Can you show an example of a `SELECT` query where this would actually make a difference?

Comment: Updated question with example

Comment: `PDO::ATTR_CASE` sets the case handling for COLUMNS ... if I understood you correctly, you get the VALUE of an entry with the wrong case? I think your problem is not in PDO, it's in the MySQL database. What collation is your table using?

Comment: ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 collation=uf8_general_ci

Comment: Did you run your query with PHPMyAdmin or a similar tool? I suspect that you have multiple entries with the same slug but different case spellings. Since you are using a case insensitive collation (_ci) You may get an entry with a different spelling as you provided.

Comment: You're right, I will switch to utf8_bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::ATTR_CASE` sets the case handling for **COLUMNS** ... if I understood you correctly, you get the **VALUE** of an entry with the wrong case?

Did you run your query with PHPMyAdmin or a similar tool? I suspect that you have multiple entries with the same slug but different case spellings (pdc vs pDc). Since you are using a case insensitive collation (_ci) You may get an entry with a different spelling as you provided, not the one you expected.

For a single query you can use a differenct collation like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    uploads
WHERE 
    slug COLLATE utf8_bin = :slug
LIMIT 1
```

If you want this behaviour to be the default, you can change the collation for the whole table.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Comment: You are correct, I can't believe I forgot to check the collation! Thank you!